# xcode random number generator

Tags: objective-c, xcode, facebook, random

i am building an app that shows a random facebook profile picture but do not know how to make the profile id a random number. I can obviously change it randomly in the code but need it to be random. It is the second NSString down that i need to be random. ANy help would be much appreciated!

```
- (IBAction) nextImagePush {
    NSString *prefix = @"http://graph.facebook.com/";
    NSString *profileId = @"517418970";
    NSString *suffix = @"/picture?type=large";
    NSString* url= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", prefix, profileId, suffix];
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]];
    [imageView setImage:img];
```

Comment: If I help you will you exclude my profile ID in your application?

Comment: Why would you possibly want to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NSString *profileId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.10u", arc4random()];
NSLog(@"profileId: %@", profileId);
```

NSLog output:

```
profileId: 1375609947
```

Updated to use `arc4random_uniform`.
For an unbiased integer within a range:

```
+ (u_int32_t)randomInRangeLo:(u_int32_t)loBound toHi:(u_int32_t)hiBound {
    int32_t   range = hiBound - loBound + 1;
    u_int32_t random = arc4random_uniform(range);

    return loBound + random;
}

NSString *profileId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.9u", [AppDelegate randomInRangeLo:0 toHi:999999999]];
NSLog(@"profileId: %@", profileId);
```

NSLog output:

```
profileId: 2500425665
```

Using SecRandomCopyBytes will require including the header file:

```
#import <Security/SecRandom.h>
```

and the Framework:

```
Security.framework.
```

Better yet for versions or OS X >= 10.7 or iOS >= 4.3 use `arc4random_uniform`

```
+ (u_int32_t)randomInRangeLo:(u_int32_t)loBound toHi:(u_int32_t)hiBound
{
    int32_t   range = hiBound - loBound + 1;
    return loBound + arc4random_uniform(range);
}
```

Comment: This works great thanks although it sometimes returns minus numbers, for example -236716805 is there any way to modify this code to make it so only positive numbers are returned?

Comment: -1. Never use arc4random() unless you understand the caveats (namely it is documented as being thread-unsafe unless you do your own locking, so it's generally unsafe for use in library code). The return type is also `u_int32_t` which is why it appears to give negative numbers when formatting with "%d" (more importantly, undefined behaviour), and the call to `abs()` strictly results in undefined behaviour too.

Comment: `rand_r()` is presumably thread-safe and signal-safe. Then there's `SecRandomCopyBytes()` (which probably does an open/read/close of `/dev/urandom`) or a Mersenne Twister (which there are plenty of libraries for). RC4 is not particularly fast and cryptographically weak, making it a poor choice for most uses.

Comment: From Man: rand_r() "this function will be a weak pseudo-random generator" and it depends on a random seed, it shouldn't be used. SecRandomCopyBytes() is an excellent choice, is it thread safe?  The Mersenne Twister and RC4 are really well beyond this question/usage and the thread safeness depend on the particular implementation.

Comment: `SecRandomCopyBytes()` is almost certainly the wrong thing to use here too (Since when does selecting a "random" facebook profile require a secure random number generator?), and is going to be *much* slower, and reading arbitrary bytes into a uint32_t *might* be undefined behaviour, and it's still not safe to format a u_int32_t with %d, and will likely give a warning in future compilers (it might already give a warning with the Clang frontend).

Comment: @tc I agree that SecRandomCopyBytes () is overkill, that was your suggestion. My feeling is that arc4random is indeed a reasonable solution for this usage.  The %d in place of %u was an accident I have corrected, thanks.  But it seems that there is no solution that suits you, should Harry just give up?  Again I ask: please provide an acceptable solution.

Comment: My point was that you've said "never use rand() or random()" in comments elsewhere, while proposing `arc4random()` which is slower, still insecure, documented as thread-unsafe, and may be statistically weak (the second output byte of RC4 is heavily biased). `random()` is reasonably fast, reasonably portable, and was thread-safe the last time I looked at the source code.

Comment: For the sake of SO users I propose a solution.  Provide an answer to the OP's question, I will delete all of my comments to this question, you can delete yours if you choose.  I will up-vote your solution and you can keep your down-vote on this question.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to pick a random integer with a function such as [`rand(3)`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/rand.3.html), [`random(3)`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/random.3.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/random), or [`arc4random(3)`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/arc4random.3.html) and then use `+[NSString stringWithFormat:]` to turn that into a string using the `%u` format specifier.

What's much harder is ensuring that the integer you pick corresponds to a *valid* Facebook user ID:

- Does Facebook document anywhere what the possible valid IDs are?
- Are they always within a certain range?
- Are all IDs in that range valid?
- Is there any way to query the range of valid IDs?

If the answer to all of those questions is "yes", then you can do it, otherwise it's going to be next to impossible unless Facebook provides an API for what you want, which I think is unlikely.

Comment: Im not sure about the specific format for the profiles but having just added some of the code above it appears that when looking at the debugger console a number with a - in front of it does not return a picture but ones without it do, for example:  2011-10-03 22:33:36.096 FacebookPictures[12687:207] profileId: 1159988985
2011-10-03 22:33:36.623 FacebookPictures[12687:207] profileId: 1159988985
2011-10-03 22:33:40.213 FacebookPictures[12687:207] profileId: -1040500245
2011-10-03 22:33:40.615 FacebookPictures[12687:207] profileId: -1040500245

Comment: How could i make it so that if the returned number does have a - before it, that number is skipped until one without a - is generated?

Comment: Never use rand() or random(), always use arc4random().

Comment: Yeah ive used the code you gave above but pretty much half the numbers are negative is there a way to make them just positive numbers?

Comment: @Harry: Use the `%u` format specified to format it as an unsigned integer instead of a signed integer.

Answer (score 1):

to generate random numbers in a fixed interval you can use arc4random()%x.
x represents the maximum number you will want to obtain.
Of course there are other ways but this one works great.

Comment: There will be a bias towards smaller numbers but for an x many times smaller than 2^32 the bias is rather small.